# How to get latest reordered form array after drag and drop in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, reactive, formarray, form-control

I used drag and drop on nested form array. It has lot of fields. After drag and drop how can I get rearranged formArray list by this.columnsArray(i).value?

```
dropRow(event,i) {
    moveItemInArray(this.columnsArray(i).value, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
// this.columnsArray(i).controls = [...this.columnsArray(i).controls];
  }
```

When I use (this.columnsArray(i).value) formArray in moveItemInArray function, drag and drop not working.

When I use this.columnsArray(i).controls drag and drop working.

But I need updated rearranged values in this.columnsArray(i).value.

How can I get it?

Comment: What is `this.columnsArray(i)`?

Comment: @JSONDerulo  


 columnsArray(i: number): FormArray {
    return this.tablesArray().at(i).get('columns') as FormArray;
  }